# Spring Security - Not able to Mock JdbcUserDetailsManager

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-security, mockito, spring-test

I have two user details services. One is `JdbcUserDetailsManager` and other is my own customer implementation of `UserDetailsService`. Now I need to test it given below. I am not able to mock `JdbcUserDetailsManager` but I am able to mock my own custom implementation. The need is separate authentication for our customer and ourselves to other resources.

It works fine as expected but I am not able to write test case which mocks class. Below is my test class. It throws `CannotGetJdbcConnectionException` as It is hitting real database which is down.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringConfig.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@AutoConfigureWebMvc
@TestExecutionListeners(MockitoTestExecutionListener.class)
public class AuthenticationTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests{
    private static final String KNOWN_USER_MAIL = "valerian@mail.com";
    private static final String KNOWN_USER_PASSWORD = "pa$$w0rd";
    private static final String IN_MEMORY_KNOWN_USER_MAIL = "memuser";
    private static final String IN_MEMORY_KNOWN_USER_PASSWORD = "pass";

    @MockBean
    private AuthenticationUserService authenticationUserService;

    @MockBean
    private JdbcUserDetailsManager jdbcUserDetailsManager;

    @InjectMocks
    private DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Test
    public void successLoginTest() throws Exception{
        Mockito.when(authenticationUserService.getUser(KNOWN_USER_MAIL)).thenReturn(createdTenantUser(UserAccountRole.ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN));
        Mockito.when(jdbcUserDetailsManager.loadUserByUsername(KNOWN_USER_MAIL)).thenThrow(new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
        Answer<Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>> answers = (invocationOnMock) -> getRoles();

        Mockito.when(authenticationUserService.getAuthorities(KNOWN_USER_MAIL)).thenAnswer(answers);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JwtAuthenticationRequest loginInfo = new JwtAuthenticationRequest(KNOWN_USER_MAIL, KNOWN_USER_PASSWORD);

        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/auth")
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(loginInfo));

        mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.cookie().exists(AlSecurityConstants.AL_ACCESS_TOKEN));
    }
}
```

My `SpringConfig` class

```
@ComponentScan({"com.example.security"})
@ImportResource({"classpath:/spring-security-test.xml", "classpath:/spring-config.xml"})
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return Mockito.mock(CustomUserDetailService.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService jdbcManager() {
        return Mockito.mock(JdbcUserDetailsManager.class);
    }
}
```

How can I mock `JdbcUserDetailsManager` class?